# One side of the texture is light and the other dark

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm finishing my first 3D character model and I'm having problems with the textures of the boot.I put this texture that I don't remember the name on it before cutting it in UV Editing and then I made the Mark Seam and Unwrap scheme, as you can see in the image:
[image]
So I made the Mark Seam and Unwrap scheme as you can see in the image and the texture looked like this in the Shading Editor after I added the nodes to do the Normal Map:
[image]

And after adding a node to make the Base Color, its texture looked like this:[image]

What can I do to fix this? I don't think it's because of the Geometry, Bright/Contrast and ColorRamp Nodes because it happens regardless of whether I add them or not.

Comment: hello could you please pack your images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Attach *Texture Coordinate* node to the image node vector input.  You'll want to use UV to access your UV map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened and caused this problem, but I solved it by deleting the nodes of the normal map and redoing it.